# How to access phone's addressbook in turbolink enabled rails mobile app

Tags: android, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, hybrid-mobile-app, turbolinks

I have a rails 5 application using turbolink, i am building a hybrid app with that.My question is how to access phone's(android/ios) addressbook from my hybrid app to get all contacts and their information? Any suggestion or guidance is welcomed.

Update:

I think [turbolinks-android](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android) can help with this.

Comment: Are you trying to access the person's contacts from the website or are you building a native application? If you are building a native application what are you using for that? `rhodes`/`rhomobile` android or ios sdks? I do not think a rails 5 (web application) will be able to provide this functionality at all so please explain further

Comment: @engineersmnky see updates

Comment: Okay but [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) is the official developer docs for accessing and retrieving contacts